# Blank domain within a month

Tags: seo, domains, web-development

I bought a domain name for new site. Within a month, on a domain, there was nothing but an empty root directory of the page something like "`Index of / [ICO] Name Last modified Size Description`".

I read that for new domains until developing is best to make a page with a brief description of the future site. Very soon I will publish my site on hosting, will i have a negative seo impact for last month with a blank page?
Pretty nice domain, but as long as there is a possibility I can change him beforehand. Is there at least some sense to me to do so?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Spent the time you worry about this on development and you'll be just fine.

**Longer answer**:
No, it's not perfect, but it wont really have much noteworthy effect on your results. A single page, low content, temperal page doesn't get you further anyways.

If you think it'll be an improvement for you *visitors*, then invest some time on it, otherwise you can leave it be. If you feel a bit better to have a page, spend half an hour on it.